# Java Json to Json message mapper framework

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

We have implemented rest api in our Java backend application. I have to implement functionality in such a way that any json message request received by the application can be custom validated and transformed into other output json message. Example

```
Input: {
    "name" : "France",
    "language" : "French"
}

Output: {
    "country" : "France",
    "continent" : "Europe"
}
```

Input Json Message --> Custom Validation --> Mapper/Transformer --> Output Json Message

Expectation is that in this transformer framework if I could map the inbound and outbound message fields along with validation for that field so that in future if I need to change field mapping or validation, I don't need to make the code change instead just change the mapper so that input message field automatically reflect in the output json message.

```
 Mapper File:  {
    "mapper" : ["name:country"],
    "validator" : ["countryValidator"]
 }
```

Can you please suggest any framework that can help me in the above requirement otherwise I'll have to create one.

Thanks all in advance.

Comment: How about overriding Jackson `ObjectMapper` to do your custom conversion. you could then have the mapping definitions in your config

Answer (score 0):

I used data pipeline that is third party product to map the inbound and outbound fields. It can validate the inbound message and transform it to different types of message formats. I put all the mappings in the database and load into the Redis cache from their regularly loading into the JVM so that there is no performance impact. Now I have superset of inbound and outbound fields so based on inbound/outbound messages I can make the changes at runtime. This solution is running in the Production.

Comment: You may add the code the fixes the issue